# Symmetric Group Julia Cyclic notation

Tags: julia

For a fixed n,

How to list the conjugacy classes of S(n) in **JULIA**. I would like to have a List (array) with the permutations for every type of cycle.

For example, for n=3.

The list is:

(1,2,3)

(1,2)(3)

(1)(2)(3)

It would be ideal to write the permutations in cyclic notation and not like arrays. Do you know how to change this?

Comment: I have no idea what conjugacy classes are but maybe you can find what you're searching in the package [`Combinatorics.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl)

Answer (score 0):

They may not be what you are looking for, but I'd point you [here](https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl/blob/master/src/permutations.jl) (from `SymPy.jl` where you can specify a permutation in cycle form) or [here](https://github.com/scheinerman/Permutations.jl) (where this form is used for display and can be generated with the function `cycle_string`.)